# How can I Plot the annual growth rate of Area, Yield and Rainfall for 5 different crops?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to make a plot about annual growth rate but I can't make a plot.

```
growth.rate <- function(data){
  for (i in c("Area", "Rainfall", "Yield")) {
    T1 <- max(data$Year) - min(data$Year) + 1
    FV <- data[which(data$Year == max(data$Year)),i]
    SV <- data[which(data$Year == min(data$Year)),i]
    cagr <- ((FV/SV)^(1/T1)) -1
    print(cagr)}
}
```

But I need to plot the annual growth rate of Area, Yield and Rainfall for 5 different crops.

I subset my dataset for the crops:

```
data1 <- df %>% 
  filter(Crop == "Sugarcane" | Crop == "Rice" | Crop == "Coconut " | Crop == "Wheat" | Crop== "Maize")
```

I want to make a plot similar to this one, thank you in advance.:

[image]

Here for sample of my dataset:

```
structure(list(X = c(2L, 5L, 7L, 12L, 14L, 16L, 18L, 23L, 26L, 
27L, 32L, 36L, 41L, 45L, 50L, 57L, 60L, 64L, 65L, 71L, 77L, 81L, 
84L, 87L, 92L, 94L, 96L, 98L, 103L, 107L, 111L, 112L, 120L, 127L, 
129L, 134L, 138L, 139L, 144L, 148L, 149L, 154L, 158L, 159L, 164L, 
168L, 172L, 177L, 181L, 185L, 186L, 194L, 201L, 9831L, 9832L, 
9834L, 9838L, 9840L, 9841L, 9843L), State = c("Andaman and Nicobar Islands", 
"Andaman and Nicobar Islands", "Andaman and Nicobar Islands", 
"Andaman and Nicobar Islands", "Andaman and Nicobar Islands", 
"Andaman and Nicobar Islands", "Andaman and Nicobar Islands", 
"Andaman and Nicobar Islands", "Andaman and Nicobar Islands", 
"Andaman and Nicobar Islands", "Andaman and Nicobar Islands", 
"Andaman and Nicobar Islands", "Andaman and Nicobar Islands", 
"Andaman and Nicobar Islands", "Andaman and Nicobar Islands", 
"Andaman and Nicobar Islands", "Andaman and Nicobar Islands", 
"Andaman and Nicobar Islands", "Andaman and Nicobar Islands", 
"Andaman and Nicobar Islands", "Andaman and Nicobar Islands", 
"Andaman and Nicobar Islands", "Andaman and Nicobar Islands", 
"Andaman and Nicobar Islands", "Andaman and Nicobar Islands", 
"Andaman and Nicobar Islands", "Andaman and Nicobar Islands", 
"Andaman and Nicobar Islands", "Andaman and Nicobar Islands", 
"Andaman and Nicobar Islands", "Andaman and Nicobar Islands", 
"Andaman and Nicobar Islands", "Andaman and Nicobar Islands", 
"Andaman and Nicobar Islands", "Andaman and Nicobar Islands", 
"Andaman and Nicobar Islands", "Andaman and Nicobar Islands", 
"Andaman and Nicobar Islands", "Andaman and Nicobar Islands", 
"Andaman and Nicobar Islands", "Andaman and Nicobar Islands", 
"Andaman and Nicobar Islands", "Andaman and Nicobar Islands", 
"Andaman and Nicobar Islands", "Andaman and Nicobar Islands", 
"Andaman and Nicobar Islands", "Andaman and Nicobar Islands", 
"Andaman and Nicobar Islands", "Andaman and Nicobar Islands", 
"Andaman and Nicobar Islands", "Andaman and Nicobar Islands", 
"Andaman and Nicobar Islands", "Andaman and Nicobar Islands", 
"Arunachal Pradesh", "Arunachal Pradesh", "Arunachal Pradesh", 
"Arunachal Pradesh", "Arunachal Pradesh", "Arunachal Pradesh", 
"Arunachal Pradesh"), Year = c(2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2001L, 2001L, 
2001L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2003L, 2003L, 2004L, 2004L, 2005L, 
2005L, 2006L, 2006L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2000L, 2000L, 
2000L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2004L, 
2004L, 2004L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2005L, 2005L, 
2005L), Season = c("Kharif     ", "Whole Year ", "Whole Year ", 
"Kharif     ", "Whole Year ", "Whole Year ", "Kharif     ", "Whole Year ", 
"Whole Year ", "Kharif     ", "Whole Year ", "Kharif     ", "Whole Year ", 
"Kharif     ", "Whole Year ", "Whole Year ", "Whole Year ", "Autumn     ", 
"Autumn     ", "Rabi       ", "Whole Year ", "Kharif     ", "Whole Year ", 
"Whole Year ", "Kharif     ", "Whole Year ", "Whole Year ", "Kharif     ", 
"Whole Year ", "Whole Year ", "Autumn     ", "Autumn     ", "Rabi       ", 
"Whole Year ", "Kharif     ", "Whole Year ", "Whole Year ", "Kharif     ", 
"Whole Year ", "Whole Year ", "Kharif     ", "Whole Year ", "Whole Year ", 
"Kharif     ", "Whole Year ", "Whole Year ", "Kharif     ", "Whole Year ", 
"Whole Year ", "Autumn     ", "Autumn     ", "Rabi       ", "Whole Year ", 
"Kharif     ", "Kharif     ", "Rabi       ", "Whole Year ", "Kharif     ", 
"Kharif     ", "Rabi       "), Crop = c("Rice", "Coconut ", "Sugarcane", 
"Rice", "Coconut ", "Sugarcane", "Rice", "Coconut ", "Sugarcane", 
"Rice", "Coconut ", "Rice", "Coconut ", "Rice", "Coconut ", "Coconut ", 
"Sugarcane", "Rice", "Sugarcane", "Maize", "Coconut ", "Rice", 
"Coconut ", "Sugarcane", "Rice", "Coconut ", "Sugarcane", "Rice", 
"Coconut ", "Sugarcane", "Rice", "Sugarcane", "Maize", "Coconut ", 
"Rice", "Coconut ", "Sugarcane", "Rice", "Coconut ", "Sugarcane", 
"Rice", "Coconut ", "Sugarcane", "Rice", "Coconut ", "Sugarcane", 
"Rice", "Coconut ", "Sugarcane", "Rice", "Sugarcane", "Maize", 
"Coconut ", "Maize", "Rice", "Wheat", "Sugarcane", "Maize", "Rice", 
"Wheat"), Area = c(102, 18168, 1, 83, 18190, 1, 189.2, 18240, 
5, 52, 18284.74, 52.94, 18394.7, 2.09, 13876.57, 14358, 0.2, 
3.5, 13.4, 3.84, 14560, 10779, 6992, 141, 9718, 7015, 81, 6854.3, 
3575, 71.3, 6791, 73.33, 86.7, 3668, 10695.8, 7060, 455, 10509.37, 
7110, 268, 10681.98, 7156.7, 145.26, 8683.38, 7050.45, 128.02, 
921.87, 3483.09, 53.5, 1595.5, 67.5, 73, 3540, 2453, 3342, 30, 
5, 3000, 3400, 32), Production = c(321, 65100000, 2, 300, 64430000, 
1, 510.84, 67490000, 40, 90.17, 68580000, 72.57, 52380000, 12.06, 
52030000, 59370000, 0.5, 10, 41.75, 18.22, 71300000, 31863, 23900000, 
3736, 27033, 25250000, 2379, 18995.62, 15400000, 1500, 20118, 
889.2, 96.4, 12700000, 31600.82, 26830000, 13760, 30760.7, 26660000, 
2879.52, 29119.66, 34750000, 1560, 25870.98, 26430000, 2448.2, 
2539.64, 14190000, 999.5, 3788, 402, 253, 1.1e+07, 2674, 1914, 
60, 50, 2700, 5000, 65), Rainfall = c(2763.2, 2763.2, 2763.2, 
3080.9, 3080.9, 3080.9, 2620.2, 2620.2, 2620.2, 2355.9, 2355.9, 
2460.1, 2460.1, 2954.7, 2954.7, 2404.7, 2404.7, 3157.1, 3157.1, 
3157.1, 3157.1, 2763.2, 2763.2, 2763.2, 3080.9, 3080.9, 3080.9, 
2404.7, 2404.7, 2404.7, 3157.1, 3157.1, 3157.1, 3157.1, 2620.2, 
2620.2, 2620.2, 2355.9, 2355.9, 2355.9, 2460.1, 2460.1, 2460.1, 
2954.7, 2954.7, 2954.7, 2404.7, 2404.7, 2404.7, 3157.1, 3157.1, 
3157.1, 3157.1, 2545.7, 2545.7, 2545.7, 2545.7, 2335.5, 2335.5, 
2335.5), Yield = c(3.14705882352941, 3583.22324966975, 2, 3.6144578313253, 
3542.05607476636, 1, 2.7, 3700.10964912281, 8, 1.73403846153846, 
3750.66859031083, 1.37079712882508, 2847.5593513349, 5.77033492822967, 
3749.48564378661, 4134.97701629753, 2.5, 2.85714285714286, 3.11567164179104, 
4.74479166666667, 4896.97802197802, 2.95602560534372, 3418.19221967963, 
26.4964539007092, 2.78174521506483, 3599.42979330007, 29.3703703703704, 
2.77134353617437, 4307.69230769231, 21.0378681626928, 2.96245030187012, 
12.1260057275331, 1.1118800461361, 3462.37731733915, 2.95450737672731, 
3800.28328611898, 30.2417582417582, 2.92697849633232, 3749.64838255977, 
10.7444776119403, 2.72605453296112, 4855.58986683807, 10.7393638992152, 
2.9793674813264, 3748.69689168776, 19.1235744414935, 2.75487867052838, 
4073.96880356235, 18.6822429906542, 2.37417737386399, 5.95555555555556, 
3.46575342465753, 3107.34463276836, 1.0900937627395, 0.572710951526032, 
2, 10, 0.9, 1.47058823529412, 2.03125)), row.names = c(NA, 60L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

This gets you fairly close:

```r
library(tidyverse)

crop_data %>%
  group_by(Crop, Year) %>%
  summarize(across(c(Area, Production, Yield), sum)) %>%
  group_by(Crop) %>%
  mutate(across(c(Area, Production, Yield),
                ~ (.x/lag(.x)) / c(1, diff(Year)) - 1)) %>%
  summarize(across(c(Area, Production, Yield), ~mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
  pivot_longer(-1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Crop, value, fill = name)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(), color = "white", size = 2, width = 0.7) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, size = 1) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = ~ scales::percent(.x, accuracy = 1)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1") +
  theme_classic(base_size = 20) +
  labs(fill = "", y = "Average annual growth rate", x = "") +
  theme(legend.position = "top",
        axis.line.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        legend.key.size = unit(10, "mm"))
```

[image]

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: @MustafaYusufAksoy what do you mean? If you store the sample data you provided as `crop_data and run the above code, you get the plot. That's how I created it. Are you getting an error message?

Comment: I am getting this error "`summarise()` has grouped output by 'Crop'. You can override using the `.groups` argument."

Comment: @MustafaYusufAksoy that's not an error. It's a message, and it is expected. Are you not getting a plot?

Comment: I am getting but it is not like yours.

Comment: @MustafaYusufAksoy maybe that's because you have all the data, but I only have a small part of it?

Comment: I can't see any data of Maize, Rice Wheat in the plot.

Comment: maybe you are right your data is smaller but I can't see any data these of them.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/10WJlyiu7b9QFayWTE0GdggHPG_VA4pZB6dg4V9fP27A/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: could you shrae the csv on google docs?

Comment: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/chinmaynagesh/crop-yield-per-state-andrainfall-
data-of-india